# How to plot degree distribution at intermediate steps

Tags: r

I created a network with the Barabasi-Albert model. Now I have to plot degree distribution at intermediate steps.

For example, the network that I created has 5000 total nodes. 
Now I want to plot degree distribution when the network has 2000 nodes, 3000 nodes and when the network has 5000 nodes.

How can I do?

This is my code:

```
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)

initialNet <- erdos.renyi.game(n = 4, p.or.m = 1) 

net <- sample_pa(n = 5000, m = 4, directed = FALSE, start.graph = initialNet) 

netdd <- degree_distribution(net, mode = "all", cumulative = TRUE) # this works for N = 5000, and when N = 2000 and N = 3000?
```

Thank you

---

Networks generated with Barabasi-Albert model follows a power-law degree distribution with *gamma = 3*.
So the 3 intermediate graphics that I expect are:
[image]

Instead, the "total" graphic which represents the degree dynamics, that is the growth of the nodes as a function of time is this:

[image]

I'm sorry for poor image quality.

Comment: This appears to be just another instance of the question you asked yesterday. Maybe you should be asking on a site that is set up to offer statistical advice? SO is for coders who can offer an algorithm for a process that is well-described.

Comment: @42- I'm sorry but the question today is not about the one yesterday. Anyway I apologize.

Comment: What variables do you want to plot? How do you expect the plot to look at the end? What kind of graph should it be? Feel free to post a picture of a hand-drawn figure you're trying to plot.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks Roman for the reply, I edited my main message.

Comment: What is t, K and P in your code?